# Adding reference attachment to email responds missing SourceUrl parameter

Tags: c#, .net-core, office365, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I'm trying to send an email with an attachment bigger than 4MB through Microsoft Graph.
Searching around the web I came to the conclusion that for files bigger than 4MB, I would need to upload the file to onedrive through an upload session, and then add it to the email as a "reference attachment".

So far my code looks like this, first I upload the file to one drive

```
var graphClient = GetGraphClient();
var rootItem = graphClient.Users[userEmail].Drive.Root.Request().GetAsync().Result;
uploadSession = graphClient.Users[userEmail].Drive.Items[rootItem.Id].ItemWithPath(fullFileName).CreateUploadSession().Request().PostAsync().Result;

fullFileByteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(content);
stream = new MemoryStream(fullFileByteArray);

provider = new ChunkedUploadProvider(uploadSession, graphClient, stream);
driveItem = provider.UploadAsync(3).Result;
```

This works just fine, I upload the file to one drive and I get the id of said file. Next step is creating the email as a draft.

`var email = await graphClient.Users[fromEmail].Messages.Request().AddAsync(message);`

This also works fine, I create the email as a draft (I can see it on outlook), and I get the Id of said attachment.

Now onto the problematic part, when I try to add the attachments to the draft email.

```
foreach (var att in fileAttachments)
{
     var attachment = new ReferenceAttachment();
     attachment.Name = att.FullFileName;
     attachment.ContentType = att.MIMEType;
     attachment.Id = att.FileId;
     attachment.ODataType = "#microsoft.graph.referenceAttachment";
     attachment.Size = att.Size;
     attachmentsParsed.Add(attachment);

     await graphClient.Users[fromEmail].Messages[email.Id].Attachments.Request().AddAsync(attachment);
}
```

When I try to execute the AddAsync() it responds with:

```
Message: The property 'SourceUrl' is required when creating the entity.
Inner error:
        AdditionalData:
        request-id: {{someId}}
        date: {{someDate}}
ClientRequestId: {{someId}}
) ---> Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: ErrorInvalidProperty
Message: The property 'SourceUrl' is required when creating the entity.
Inner error:
        AdditionalData:
        request-id: {{someId}}
        date: {{someDate}}
ClientRequestId: {{someId}}
```

The thing is ReferenceAttachment does not have a SourceUrl property, neither do I find a sourceUrl parameter in the response from uploading the file. I tried adding it to the AdditionalData property of the attachment, which is a Dictionary, but it didn't work.

Also tried to send the request through Postman like this (tried to send it to the beta version of the API too):

```
{
    "name":"{{someName}}",
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.referenceAttachment",
    "sourceUrl": "{{someUrl}}",
    "contentType":"text/plain",
    "id":"{{someId}}",
    "size":"1553",
}
```

And the response was

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ErrorInvalidProperty",
    "message": "The property 'SourceUrl' is required when creating the entity.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "{{someId}}",
      "date": "{{someDate}}"
    }
  }
}
```

Where do I add this SourceUrl property and where do I get it from?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the uploading of large file attachments directly to the Message without having to upload to onedrive first. This is described in the link below.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-large-attachments?tabs=http

There now exists support for this scenario in the latest version of the .Net SDK in the form of a LargeFileUploadTask.

Essentially, you will need to do the following steps

1. create an upload session for the attachment as follows. (Note that this available in the beta library for now https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph.Beta/0.10.0-preview)

```cs
var fileStream; // file stream you wish to upload to the attachment

var attachmentItem = new AttachmentItem
{
    AttachmentType = AttachmentType.File,
    Name = "flower",
    Size = fileStream.Length
};

await graphClient.Me.Messages[email.Id].Attachments
    .CreateUploadSession(attachmentItem)
    .Request()
    .PostAsync();
```

2. Create the task using the stream you wish to upload.

```cs
// Create task
LargeFileUploadTask<FileAttachment> largeFileUploadTask = new LargeFileUploadTask<FileAttachment>(uploadSession, fileStream);
```

3. (Optional) You can setup monitoring of the upload progress as by creating an instance of IProgress

```cs
// Setup the progress monitoring
IProgress<long> progress = new Progress<long>(progress =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Uploaded {progress} bytes of {stream.Length} bytes");
});
```

4. Upload the attachment to the message!

```
UploadResult<DriveItem> uploadResult = null;
try
{
    uploadResult = await largeFileUploadTask.UploadAsync(progress);

    if (uploadResult.UploadSucceeded)
    {
        //File attachement uplaod only returns the location URI on successful upload
        Console.WriteLine($"File Uploaded {uploadResult.Location}");//Sucessful Upload
    }
}
catch (ServiceException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

If you query the attachment of the message you should now view the attachement you added without any worries

```cs
var attachements = await graphClient.Me.Messages[email.Id].Attachments.Request().GetAsync();
```